# SCNetworkReachabilityFlags are sometimes not being set correctly when connection is lost/gained

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Ive been testing connectivity loss in an app of mine during a queue of connections and Ive noticed I am able to get my app into a state where it incorrectly recognizes connectivity.  Either saying there is a connection when there isn't or that there is not a connection when there is.

Ive traced the issue down to the SCNetworkReachabilityFlags being incorrect at the time I am checking for connectivity.  And these flags remain until the connection state changes.  So in effect theres no way to get the app out of the incorrect state short of restarting it, or a connection notification firing properly

I am using apple's reachability.m found here  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_8

and the issue is in the 'networkStatusForFlags' method.  Basically the flag being passed in is incorrect.  My machine the simulator runs on will have a connection with WIFI, but the flag being returned is still triggering on kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable.

is there any way to solve this issue?  I feel like flags being incorrect is a core apple problem with SCNetworkReachabilityFlags, but i feel like if that was the case this would be more of a widespread issue.

Comment: wow I could have written this question myself. I have exactly the same problem! Looking at the docs, they say that the flags only indicate that the packet could be sent, not that the target host actually receives the packet: "A remote host is considered reachable when a data packet, sent by an application into the network stack, can leave the local device. Reachability does not guarantee that the data packet will actually be received by the host.".

Comment: The flags do seem to work in some cases. For example, if I initially start my app, the correctly indicate failure. However, backgrounding the app, configuring 100% network loss using the Network Link Conditioner, and then re-foregrounding the app, the flags don't realise that the network is no longer reachable.